# Grails: test domain object constraints

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I'm trying to test the constraints of my `User` domain class

```
class UserTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        mockForConstraintsTests(User)
    }

    void testEmailConstraint() {

        // Test e-mail validation
        def user = new User(userRealName: 'bob', passwd: 'foo')

        // Check null not allowed
        saveAndVerifyError user, 'email', 'nullable'       
    }

    private void saveAndVerifyError(User user, String field, String constraintName) {

        assertFalse user.validate()
        assertEquals constraintName, user.errors[field]
    }
}
```

I got the information about how to do this on [this webpage](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/04/unit-testing-constraints-in-domain.html), but when I run this test I get the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addValidateMethod_closure83.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:973)
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addValidateMethod_closure84.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:1014)
at com.mycompany.security.UserTests.saveAndVerifyError(UserTests.groovy:31)
at com.mycompany.security.UserTests.this$6$saveAndVerifyError(UserTests.groovy)
at com.mycompany.security.UserTests$this$6$saveAndVerifyError.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at com.mycompany.security.UserTests.testEmailConstraint(UserTests.groovy:18)
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is [a bug in Grails 1.3.3](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6482?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel). The following changes workaround this problem

```
protected void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager = [hasGrailsPlugin: {String name -> true }] as GrailsPluginManager
    mockForConstraintsTests(User)
}

protected void tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
    PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager = null
}
```